# Getting state values in simple component - Class VS Functional (Class working, functional not working). Why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

For getting values via `state` I made simple example. I got 2 simple components - 1) Class Based 2) Functional Based.

I am new to React so trying out both options. For class, its working, for Functional it is not. Please help.

**Case-I : Class (working)**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class HomeClass extends Component {

  state = {
    name: "Jack Rogers",
    age: 25,
    city: "New York"
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{this.state.name + "/" +  this.state.age + "/" +  this.state.city }</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default HomeClass;
```

**Case-II: Functional (x Not Working)**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const HomeFunctional = () => {

  [details, setDetails] = useState({name: "Jack Rogers", age: 29, city: "New York"})

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{this.details.name + "/" + this.details.age + "/" + this.details.city}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default HomeFunctional;
```

**Error:**

[image]

Comment: You lack a `const` in front of `[details, ...`

Comment: I guess they think the poster should have learned this answer from the document.

Comment: You should try vscode, it'll tell you when you have syntax errors. Maybe with eslint plugin and [exhaustive deps](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14920) if you plan to use react hooks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do with `const` the instantiation and without `this`.

Try the following:

```
const HomeFunctional = () => {
  const [details, setDetails] = useState({name: "Jack Rogers", age: 29, city: "New York"})

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{details.name + "/" + details.age + "/" + details.city}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I hope this helps!